# Google drive files downloaded on my computer do not open when offline

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been trying to set up the Google drive offline. I've followed every step in the [doc](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375012)  and I'm able to access my files when I'm offline by going to [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com).

I've also downloaded the app for my computer (I'm using a Mac). I see all the files in the Google Drive folder, but these files seem to be mere links to the online versions of the files... so when I click on them and I'm offline, I get an error message saying that there's no internet connection.

Is there a way to configure the Google drive app so that it redirects to the correct link in Chrome? If not, what is the benefit of using the app at all?

Answer (score 1):

- When offline, accessing real Google Docs should be via https://drive.google.com/#offline
- There is benefit to having Drive for PC or MAC as an offline user when using non-google docs documents or files such as a Photoshop file.

Good example use case: spreadsheets offline editing is currently not supported in Drive. If you travel and you have some serious spreadsheet stuff to do, you can put an MS Excel on your drive and edit it with Microsoft Excel. When you're back online, Drive for PC/Mac will sync it automatically.

I'm currently writing a guide to Google Apps Offline Usage:

http://www.mincko.com/nl/articles/The-Complete-Guide-To-Google-Drive-Offline

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "Google Drive offline" shows files but not folders, so you have all your files sorted in one sole column. The only order available is "most recently modified", but that's not an order, that's actually a **chaos**. I can't work like that and I can't understand which is the purpose of that... (I'm using Windows 8.1)
If I double click to my *Google Drive* foler (in `c:\users\username\Google Drive\`), a Chrome windows opens with not internet connection message.

Comment: glad im not the only one! This is a massive turn off! I go to offline mode and all 600 of my files are there is one huge list with no folder structure. Useless